# Slow performance of addclass to body on mobile

Tags: jquery, performance, addclass

I have some jquery that is very slow on mobile and I've been trying to debug the exact piece which is causing the issue.

I seem to have identified that the following line:

```
$("body").toggleClass('noscroll');
```

Where the class noscroll is as follows:

```
.noscroll{
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Any insights as to why this would be especially slow on mobile devices?

Thanks!

Comment: How about try to change to `add / removeClass` ? It's slightly faster than `toggleClass`.

Comment: What specifically is slow about this? Is it slow to add the class, or that the effect the class should have it slow to be added?

Comment: Position `fixed` is [buggy on mobile](http://bradfrost.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/). Try some plugin to do that with javascript.